# GROUP BY table1.column_name ORDER BY table2.column_name

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a table of posts, and a table of users, and I have a table in-between that has the relationships between the two. One user can have many posts etc.

The posts can be 'starred' by adding a 0 or 1 into the starred column on posts table. Only one post will be starred per user, but some users will have no starred posts.

I need to create a query that pulls one post per user (so I am using 'group by'), and of those posts it should get the starred one, not all users will have a starred post so I can't just use

```
WHERE starred = 1
```

Essentially I want to order the group by starred so it gets the starred post if there is one and a normal one if there isn't.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
   posts.post_title
FROM
   posts
INNER JOIN rel_company_post ON posts.post_id = rel_company_post.post_id
INNER JOIN companies ON rel_company_post.company_id = companies.company_id
GROUP BY companies.company_id
ORDER BY posts.starred DESC
```

Comment: if a user has no starred post, which post do you want to get? a specific one, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: The starring system is only for if the company has > 1 post. They can choose which one to show on that specific page. The companied that dont have a star will only have 1 post ergo it wont matter. Thanks very much for geting back to me BTW

Answer (score 0):

First, without further information, your intermediate table seems unnecessary. Add a column "company_id" to the posts table so you can see directly the owner of the post, and eliminate the middle table.

second you are looking for "max" i.e.

select max(starred), posts.post_title

if you put company_id in the posts table, you won't even need to do a join

your overall query would thus look like

select max(starred), post_title from posts 
group by company_id

Comment: Thanks very much, I don't think I can do that as each post can also have multiple owners. If a manager runs two companies they can assign the post to both companies. Thats why I am sctractching my head :) Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly how your database is organized, i think you need something like this:

```
SELECT
   COALESCE(
     MAX(CASE WHEN posts.starred=1 THEN posts.post_title END),
     MAX(posts.post_title)
   ) title
FROM
   posts INNER JOIN rel_company_post
   ON posts.post_id = rel_company_post.post_id
   INNER JOIN companies
   ON rel_company_post.company_id = companies.company_id
GROUP BY companies.company_id
```

If there's a post that has stared=1, CASE WHEN will return the title, and MAX will be evaluated as this title. COALESCE will then return this title.

If there's no post starred, then the first MAX will return NULL, and coalesce will return the second MAX that has the maximum non starred title.